# calling an API in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

need help here: I have this api which i run in Postman (https://dev.azure.com/abc/Abc/_apis/build/builds/24169/workitems?api-version=4.1), I get result as

```
{
    "count": 50,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "21610",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/abc/_apis/wit/workItems/21610"
        },
        {
            "id": "21606",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/abc/_apis/wit/workItems/21606"
        }]}
```

I need to call this in Powershell, and get a list of all IDs. I am doing this way but I am not getting anything..what wrong am I doing?

```
Function GET-RELEASEWIT {
$AzureDevOpsPAT ='psgklxbjircg5g5fda'
    $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$uriAcc = "https://dev.azure.com/abc/ABC/_apis/build/builds/24169/workitems?api-version=4.1"
write-host $uriAcc
$responseRelW = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAcc -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
write-host $responseRelW
$BID = @()
$BID += $responseRelW.value.id

write-host "********START****************"
write-host $BID

}
```

Comment: There's no username component in your authorization header?

Comment: username is not required if you pass api in postman you will see.. it can be left blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the below and it works. Only difference I can see is that I've used `UTF8.GetBytes` instead of `ASCII.GetBytes` when converting the PAT token to a base64 string, which shouldn't cause any difference since the character mappings are the same.

```
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/abc/ABC/_apis/build/builds/24169/workitems?api-version=4.1"
$AzureDevOpsPAT ='psgklxbjircg5g5fda'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$AzureDevOpsPAT"))
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $B64Pat" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
```

Note the URI and PAT token are obviously different when I tested this, but this should work for you.